# How can I count the number of rows in multiple .csv files that meet a condition in order to plot them on a bar chart in R?

Tags: r, variant

I have a folder with many .csv files each containing a list of annotated variants from sequencing. I would like to plot a bar chart of the number of somatic variants in each file - there is an Origin column with the value "somatic" or "germline".

I have been able to plot the total number of variants by counting the rows in each file with the following code:

```
combined_data <- list.files(pattern = ".csv")

numvar <- lapply(X = combined_data, FUN = function(x) {
  length(count.fields(x, skip = 1))
})

var <- do.call(rbind,numvar)

varn <- c(as.numeric(var))

names <- c(1:41)

table <- data.frame(names, varn)

ggplot(data=table, aes(x=names, y=varn)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

While this worked to create a bar chart for the total number of variants per file, I am not sure where it would be possible to add a condition specifying to count only the rows that meet the "somatic" condition.

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with a for loop which performs the following steps:

1. Read the table
2. Add the somatic variants
3. Add the germline variants

Here is a starter in which number of variants are stored in external variables to the loop and then the loop just adds them to those from the new file read. In the end your variables will store the total number of variants assuming you have a column named "variant.class" in your tables

```
fils <- list.files(pattern = ".csv")

som.vars.n <- 0
germline.vars.n <- 0

for(fil in fils){
  fil.tab <- read.csv(fil)
  som.vars.n <- som.vars.n + sum(fil.tab$variant.class == "somatic")
  germline.vars.n <- germline.vars.n + sum(fil.tab$variant.class == "germline")
  
}
```

Please provide minimal info to reproduce the situation if you wanna get a more accurate response. Hope I gave you a general idea.
Best